# Django - Django not returning all entities from table on GET call

Tags: django, datatable, django-serializer

I have this get function:

```
def get(self, request):
    items = Post.objects.order_by('created').annotate (
        creator_name=F('creator_id__username'),
        goal_description=F('goal_id__description'),
        replies=Count('replypost', distinct=True),
        cheers=Count('cheerpost', distinct=True),
    ) .prefetch_related (
        Prefetch('photo_set', Photo.objects.order_by('created'))
    )
    serializer = FullPostDataSerializer(items, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

It should be returning all the posts ordered by time, but for some reason when I debug and return `serializer.data` all I get on the front-end is (I added a breakpoint at `serializer.data`, and it correlates with the front-end, it's just easier to present it in this way rather than a large list of results):

[image]

But when I use PGAdmin to look at the table:

[image: image2]

As you can see, there are more recent posts than september 13th. What's going on?

Serializer:

```
class FullPostDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_urls = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        source='photo_set', many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='image_url'
    )
    creator_name = serializers.SlugField()
    replies = serializers.IntegerField()
    cheers = serializers.IntegerField()
    goal_description = serializers.SlugField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('body', 'goal_id', 'created', 'creator_name', 'goal_description', 'replies', 'cheers', 'created', 'image_urls', 'uuid')
```

Post Model:

```
class Post(AbstractBaseModel):
    creator_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator_id"
    )
    goal_id = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length = 511, validators [MinLengthValidator(5)])
    hash_tags = models.ManyToManyField(HashTag)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have a custom manager (perhaps declared in `AbstractBaseModel`)? And are you sure the problem is not on the frontend? (not rendering the posts? Your image is not sufficient to confirm the problem is not there) Please see how to write a [mre].

Comment: Yes pretty sure I don't know what a custom manager is. The front end reflects the data. I just posted the FE cause it's easier to see rather than me posting a list that is the output from serializer.data

Comment: Where is this `get()` function called within your app? To understand the context, which could help

Comment: it's a function under a Post `APIView` module. Pretty standard Django you just link a URL to it and make a call I believe.

Comment: @user8714896 the ordering is asc you may require desc order in query `Post.objects.order_by('-created')` add minus (`-`) sign to get the newest first.

Comment: @Chandan yea I fixed that. Someone else I know was running this and wasn't getting any data back. Maybe it's the dummy data library I'm using? Might not be indexing the data properly or something?

Comment: @user8714896 you can check the query which is being generate so that you can be debug or is it possible to share the sample app with sample data

Comment: Can you change this `items = Post.objects.order_by(...)` to this `items = Post.objects.all().order_by(...)` - using the `.all()` method will force Django to execute a `SELECT all` statement each time the ViewSet is **instantiated** (on each call to the endpoint) - I could be mistaken but without the `.all()` method the queryset is only executed when your ViewSet is **defined** - i.e. when you reload the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are ordering the Prefetch of photos, but you are not ordering the QuerySet of Post objects.

Try:

```
items = Post.objects.order_by('created').annotate(
    ...
).prefetch_related(
    ...
).order_by('-created')
```